# Requests to payment a gateway are failed from JMeter on cloud systems

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I have a JMeter Test Plan (JMX) which simulates users placing orders and making credit card payments at the end.

The script works well when it runs from my machine. Requests to the payment gateway failed only when the script was executed from a third-party JMeter online service (e.g Redline13, Blazemeter, and Loadium).

The first request failed with the following error.
[image]

I have tried with several header configurations

1. Sending requests without any pre-defined headers
2. Setting user agent explicitly in Header Manager
   [image]
3. Enabling `Browser Compatible Headers` in the HTTP Request
   [image]

Also compared the requests generated from the third-party service provider and the requests generated from my machine. Also copied the headers and used them in the local machine.
[image]

It works well with the local machine but it continues to fail in the requests from the third-party services (Redline13, Blazemeter, and Loadium).

Any solution or direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so the message is quite expected.

The fact that the script works on your local machine and doesn't work in the cloud most probably means that the payment gateway (or its mock) is not reachable from the Internet.

You can [increase JMeter logs verbosity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for the HTTP protocol by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and compare [jmeter.log files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) from local and cloud runs, it will contain request and response details which you will be able to compare and figure out what's different.

Comment: I do agree with this --> ` As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); `  Hence the remote application should see requests coming ` . Hence the requests from JMeter should be treated as if they were from real browsers.

Comment: Also, JMeter receives response code `200` with the message `OK`. It confirms that the IPG is reachable from the JMeter.